# webSphere Cannot connect to the server process. Make sure the server is already start

Tags: java, websphere

I work with Eclipse and WebSphere and when I start the server I get the error

> Cannot connect to the server process. Make sure the server is already start

I try to start the server from command line

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv02\bin>startServer.bat server1
```

I get the following trace and the server doesn't start

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv02\bin>echo **************************************************** before setupCMDLine ***********
**************************************************** before setupCMDLine ***********

**C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv02\bin>CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\bin\setupCmdLine.bat" server1
**Denied Access****

C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\AppSrv02\bin>echo **************************************************** after setupCMDLine ***********
**************************************************** after setupCMDLine ***********
```

How can I fix this error and start the server

Answer (score -1):

The windows user account from which you're trying to start the server has insufficient operating system privileges to do so.  You either need to have your user account granted permissions to execute the files of the WebSphere App Server installation, or have the WAS administrator install it so that you can run the necessary files.  There are [several topics in the IBM Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/tpro_rootpro_nonroot_own.html) that address this and similar issues

Comment: This is wrong. My Websphere instillation directory has Full Permission for Everyone and I still get this error.